# how to run my network configuration script on one VM without having IP

Tags: powershell, vsphere

but question is how can we put our script on that VM. or how to copy our script to that VM. because we gonna configure network via script. so is there any way to access the VM without having IP or any way to copy script to that VM.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `.iso` disk image with the script and mount it as a CD/DVD Drive in vSphere client.

Comment: thanks TR for replying but is this method also works with Windows ?

Comment: Of course it does.

Comment: if i wants to mount an iso file from jump station to that VM, then is there any method for that. please help